# SyntaxError occurs when parameters are passed to a Python API’s method with Partial Application used

Tags: python, string, syntax-error, dolphindb

When using Python API, I called a method `run(script)` where Partial Application is used to fix part of parameters to `share`. However, a SyntaxError was reported:

[image]

Here is my script. Does anyone know where the problem is?

```
s.run('tb=table(1000:0, `stock`date`price, [SYMBOL,DATE,DOUBLE])')
s.run("share{tb,}", `ad)
```

Comment: Not sure how to escape in the markup, but look at the tick ad. That should be `"ad"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error lies in **ad**,  because this format is only valid in DolphinDB. In Python, you should use `'ad'` or `"ad"`.